# How to get URL, remove most of the string, and add to IFrame URL

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to do something which is basically:

"get parent url" -> "remove url up to #" (so if you have url.com#123 you get 123) -> place result in iframe URL (so you would get iframe.url.com/number=123)

Preferably using Javascript, as PHP boggles my mind too much to understand.

I tried doing:

```
var product = window.location.href;
product.replace('https://URL.com#','');
```

But then I am lost as to where to even attempt to go next.

Sorry if I sound new, but I have never tried anything like this, and I don't usually work with JS, JQuery, or PHP

Comment: `window.location.hash` -> `#123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// First, get the hash
var hash = window.location.hash;
// If hash is not empty, remove the # sign
if(hash){ hash = hash.substring(1); }
// Add it to the iframe URL
var newURL = "http://iframe.url.com/number=" + hash;
// Use it on the iframe
document.getElementById('myIframe').src = newURL;
```

Comment: Would this be used in the iframe tags as normal? So <iframe src="document.getElementById('myIframe').src = newURL;></iframe> ?

Comment: @jordsta95 No, that last line just fills the iframe's `src=""` with the newly created URL. Do not put this code in there, it stays with your javascript, separated from the HTML.

Comment: Still having issues :/ I have tried: <iframe src=""></iframe>, <iframe id="newURL"></iframe>, <iframe id="myIfame"></iframe>, and just <iframe></iframe> and nothing shows in the iframe section, so I can't even test changing the #number

Comment: @jordsta95 Ok, to make it more clear, I made a demo with 2 files. Create a new folder on your computer. Create an empty file called `index.html` and paste **[this code](http://pastebin.com/84Km5wtK)** in it. Then, create another file called `iframe.html` and paste **[this code](http://pastebin.com/9FcDWSZ8)**. Save them, and open `index.html`, see what it does, and take a look at the code and the comments. If you need more help, don't hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.` to split the url as required:

```
window.location = {
hash: '#myAnchor',
host: 'davidwalsh.name',
hostname: 'davidwalsh.name',
href: 'http://davidwalsh.name:80/article.php?s=david+walsh+blog#myAnchor',
pathname: '/article.php',
port: '80',
protocol: 'http:',
search: '?s=david+walsh+blog',
replace: 'function replace() { [native code] }',
assign: 'function assign() { [native code] }',
reload: 'function reload() { [native code] }'
}
```

Taken from [Here](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the parent window href, but then you need to manipulate the location object of the iframe.

```
var parentHash = window.location.hash;

var childFrame = window.frames["frame id"];

childFrame.src += parentHash //add parent hash to iframe url
```